# I have a problem with settings a build system to sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3

I've created a build system, which I can't see when going to tools > build system.
I saw at file explorer that There aren't any packages downloaded (hope that's helpful).
I'm trying to learn makefile with cpp, as part of an tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The build system file needs to be saved in your `Packages/User` directory, and with the `.sublime-build` extension. The `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`** (macOS: **`Sublime Text → Preferences → Browse Packages…`**):

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages` or `~/.config/sublime-text/Packages`
- macOS/OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages` or `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages` or `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages` or `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text\Data\Packages`

<sup>The exact path depends on version and whether or not you upgraded from Sublime Text 3.</sup>

Please note that if you start your build system by selecting **`Tools → Build System → New Build System…`**, then hit Save when you're done, it will automatically save in `Packages/User`.

Comment: an additional note is that the file has to have a `sublime-build` extension to be recognized as a build and appear in the menu. On some OS's the file dialog doesn't add the extension for you if you don't specify it yourself.

Comment: @OdatNurd right-o. Updated.